# trying to create threads in Dll main

Tags: c++, multithreading

I'm currently writing a cheat for a game. I'm injecting a Dll into firefox (or whatever) which then creates 2 threads to make the cheat functions work. I'm calling createThread() without any special arguments and WaitForMultipleObjects. The threads are being created but it doesn't work. I tested my code in a console application and everything works. I guess it has something to do with the WaitForMultipleObjects function but I'm not quit sure.

```
    HANDLE threads[2];

    threads[0] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, thread1, 0, 0, NULL);
    threads[1] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, thread2, 0, 0, NULL);
    WaitForMultipleObjects(2, threads, true, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(threads[0]);
    CloseHandle(threads[1]);
```

Comment: From MSDN " There are significant limits on what you can safely do in a DLL entry point." - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn633971(v=vs.85).aspx#general_best_practices for more details.

Comment: you can create threads in DllMain but you can not wait on it

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the system executes `DllMain` while holding the loader lock.  When your threads execute, they try to call `DllMain` in order to send thread attach notifications.  This requires them to wait for the loader lock, which never gets released because your first call is waiting for the threads.

Comment: @MoritzE - you can create threads. but you can not wait in DllMain. for what you at al wait ?!

Comment: @MoritzE - so what ?! absolute not need wait on thread exit. and this is error in DllMain